# Does anyone see why my preg_match RegEx is not returning results?

Tags: php

I was just helped in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692580/how-can-i-use-regex-to-solve-this) with a regex that has been verified to work. I can see it actually working on Rubular but when I plug the regex into preg_match, I get absolutely nothing.

Here is the regex with my preg_match function:

```
    preg_match('/^!!([0-9]{5}) +.*? +[MF] ([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([A-Z]{3})([A-Z]{3}) + ([A-Z])[0-9]{3}([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/', $res, $matches);
```

All I am getting is an empty array returned.

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: By the way, Rubular uses Ruby's regex engine, which is not identical to [PCRE](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/intro.pcre.php) which PHP uses.

Comment: Ahhhh... Well, that would make sense. Would you know what I need to convert to make this work?

Comment: @Daniel If you go to my other thread, you can see the examples I posted. It was a rather lengthy example I posted. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it's incredibly specific and not really usable to anyone else and probably should have just been a comment on the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have added two extra spaces into the regular expression that should not be there and that cause the match to fail.

```
/^!!([0-9]{5}) +.*? +[MF] ([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([A-Z]{3})([A-Z]{3}) + ([A-Z])...
                         ^                                          ^
                       here                                       and here
```

Whitespace is significant (by default) in regular expressions. A space in a regular expression matches a space in the target string. Removing these two spaces fixes the problem.

See it working on [ideone](http://ideone.com/bnrfJ) (this time it is a PHP example).

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(39) "!!92519 C 01 M600200BLNBRN D55420090205"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "92519"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "600"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "200"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "BLN"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "BRN"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "D"
  [7]=>
  string(4) "2009"
  [8]=>
  string(2) "02"
  [9]=>
  string(2) "05"
}
```

Comment: Mark, thank you! It does work now. Can you please recommend a good starting source for me to learn regex? I'm really a noob with expressions.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! You guys are great. I'd never have been able to do this in any reasonable amount of time without you guys.